# Package decoupling in go

Tags: go, design-patterns, dependency-injection, solid-principles, decoupling

We all know dependency injection makes packages decoupled.
But I'm a little confused about best practices of dependency injection in go.
Lets assume package User needs to access Config package.
We can pass a Config object to User methods.   In this way I can change the Config package functionality as long as the new code resolves the interfaces.
Another approach is call Config package methods directly , In these scenario I can change Config code too as long as the methods names remains the same. Like so

### Update :

What is different between these two approaches :

```
package User

func foo(config ConfigObject) {
   config.Foo()
}
```

And this one :

```
package User

import Config

func foo() {
   config.Foo()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `config.Foo` on the `config` argument to a method means that you receive an instance of some structure (possibly implementing interface `Config`) and call the method `Foo` on that instance/interface. Think of this as of calling a method of an object in OO terms:

```
package user

func foo(cfg config.Config) {
   cfg.Foo()
}
```

Calling `config.Foo` having imported the `config` package means you are calling the function `Foo` of package `config`, not of any object/struct/interface. Think of this as pure procedural programming without any objects:

```
package user

import config

func foo() {
   config.Foo()
}
```

The latter **has nothing to do with dependency injection**, the former may constitute a part of it if `Config` is an interface.

Dependency injection, on the other hand, follows generally the same rules in Go as in other languages:

> accept interfaces, supply implementations

Because in Go structs satisfy interfaces implicitly rather than explicitly (as it is the case in Java)

- the code accepting the value only needs to know about the interface and import it;
- the code implementing it does not even need to know about the interface (it can just happen that it satisfies it);
- the code that supplies the impl into a method accepting an
  interface, obviously, needs to know both.

For your example this means:

```
package config

type Config interface {
    Foo() string
}

package foo

type Foo struct{}

func (f *Foo) Foo() string {
    return "foo"
}

package boo

type Boo struct{}

func (b *Boo) Foo() string {
    return "boo" 
}

package main

func foo(cfg config.Config) string{
    return cfg.Foo()
}

func main() {
    // here you inject an instance of Foo into foo(Config)
    
    log.Print(foo(&foo.Foo{}))

    // here you inject an instance of Boo into foo(Config)
    log.Print(foo(&boo.Boo{})
}
```

Prints

> 2018/03/03 13:32:12 foo
>
> 2018/03/03 13:32:12 boo

Comment: The example is horrible in the way it uses names (foo/Foo/foo). Even, when correct, it would confuse 100 times less, if the foo package in example is named pkg1 or anything but foo. :)

Comment: @MBODM From what I know, one can suggest/make an edit if the example is not to your liking...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Had been the better way. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Since, in my opinion, the example code given by previous poster(s) could be a bit less confusing for beginners, just by renaming things, i quickly try to do this here:

```golang
package contracts

type IConfig interface {
    GetSomeString() string
}
```

```golang
package pkg1

type Foo struct{}

func (f *Foo) GetSomeString() string {
    return "hello“
}
```

```golang
package pkg2

type Boo struct{}

func (b *Boo) GetSomeString() string {
    return "world" 
}
```

```golang
package main

func run(config contracts.IConfig) string {
    s := config.GetSomeString()
    return s
}
 
func main() {
    foo := &pkg1.Foo{}
    result1 := run(foo)
    log.Print(result1)

    boo := &pkg2.Boo{}
    result2 := run(boo)
    log.Print(result2)

    // Prints: helloworld

    // You learned:
    // Since the run() func use a IConfig interface as
    // parameter, the run() func can handle both struct
    // types (Foo and Boo) as input, because both struct
    // types (Foo and Boo) implement the IConfig interface.
}
```